# include page(s) and print duplex

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a web forum that i need to print two copies of. The firs page i need it to print in color with duplexing (double sided) the second time i need it to print black and white with duplexing (double sided). I know how to handle the printing of the forum(s) but want i am not sure of is, is there a way i can include 2 files that are saved on the server to print on the back side (the duplex side) of the two pages?

for example: 
page one (color page) includes pageone.php and prints duplex
page two (black and white page) includes pagetwo.php and prints duplex.

Comment: You could serve the pages as `PDF` or an open document format, but I don't think you get to control the printer settings unless you have some kind of client code that can run outside of the Javascript sandbox. For example: I have done automatic printing and printer options via ActiveX control, but that worked only in IE

Comment: ok so my only other option is just render all 4 pages and then have the end user print in duplex mode

Comment: You may be able to think up a creative solution, and please post it if you do. Unfortunately browser support for printing is mixed; Chrome lets you use CSS to decide whether to print background images, for example, but IE and FF do not. People usually use ActiveX if they need specialized printing for intranet apps because most businesses run Windows and IE (though landscape is shifting toward iPads and stuff, which complicates printing even further). Also not all printers support duplex. Maybe just show a message to user to recommend to print in duplex for best results?